# What is the difference between using strcpy and equating the addresses of strings?

Tags: c, pointers

I am not able to understand the difference between strcpy function and the method of equating the addresses of the strings using a pointer.The code given below would make my issue more clear. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//code to take input of strings in an array of pointers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
int main()
{
    //suppose the array of pointers is of 10 elements
    char *strings[10],string[50],*p;
    int length;
    //proper method to take inputs:
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %49[^\n]",string);
        length = strlen(string);
        p = (char *)malloc(length+1);
        strcpy(p,string);//why use strcpy here instead of p = string
        strings[i] = p; //why use this long way instead of writing directly strcpy(strings[i],string) by first defining malloc for strings[i]
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: On one of the first pages of every good C book: arrays can not be assigned in C. (!) C strings are arrays of `char`. To copy an array, some loop must be used. `strcpy()` provides a function to copy C strings that way (considering that C strings are terminated with `\0`). Btw. `strings[i] = p;` assigns pointer `p` (an address) to `strings[i]`. Afterwards, `strings[i]` and `p` point to the same storage. (The address is copied - not the contents at pointed memory.)

Comment: @Scheff but then how is strings[ i ] = p working? Aren't the last two statements contradicting?

Comment: @Scheff Yup taking my time!

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for a nice point. Made things a bit clear to me!

Comment: If not minding that some "extra space may be allocated", simply malloc (for 50 characters; 49 + NUL) and use that to scanf - no extra copy is needed.

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah that can be done too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short introduction into the magic of pointers:

```
char *strings[10],string[50],*p;
```

These are three variables with distinct types:

```
char *strings[10]; // an array of 10 pointers to char
char string[50]; // an array of 50 char
char *p; // a pointer to char
```

Then the followin is done (10 times):

```
    scanf(" %49[^\n]",string);
```

Read C string from input and store it into `string` considering that a 0 terminator must fit in also.

```
    length = strlen(string);
```

Count non-0 characters until 0 terminator is found and store in `length`.

```
    p = (char *)malloc(length+1);
```

Allocate memory on heap with length + 1 (for 0 terminator) and store address of that memory in `p`. (`malloc()` might fail. A check `if (p != NULL)` wouldn't hurt.)

```
    strcpy(p,string);//why use strcpy here instead of p = string
```

Copy C string in `string` to memory pointed in `p`. `strcpy()` copies until (inclusive) 0 terminator is found in source.

```
    strings[i] = p;
```

Assign `p` (the pointer to memory) to `strings[i]`. (After assignment `strings[i]` points to the same memory than `p`. The assignment is a pointer assignment but not the assignment of the value to which is pointed.)

---

Why `strcpy(p,string);` instead of `p = string`:

The latter would assign address of `string` (the local variable, probably stored on stack) to `p`.

1. The address of allocated memory (with `malloc()`) would have been lost. (This introduces a memory leak - memory in heap which cannot be addressed by any pointer in code.)
2. `p` would now point to the local variable in `string` (for every iteration in `for` loop). Hence afterwards, all entries of `strings[10]` would point to `string` finally.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *strings[10]---- --------->1.
strcpy(strings[i],string) ----->2.
strings[i] = string ----------->3.


p = (char *)malloc(length+1); -|
strcpy(p,string);              |-> 4.
strings[i] = p;----------------|
```

> 1. `strings` is an array of pointers, each pointer must point to valid memory.
> 2. Will lead undefined behavior since `strings[i]` is not pointing to valid memory.
> 3. Works but every pointer of `strings` will point to same location thus each will have same contents.
> 4. Thus create the new memory first, copy the contents to it and assign that memory to `strings[i]`

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` copies a particular string into allocated memory. Assigning pointers doesn't actually copy the string, just sets the second pointer variable to the same value as the first.

```
strcpy(char *destination, char *source);
```

copies from source to destination until the function finds '\0'. This function is not secure and should not be used - try `strncpy` or `strlcpy` instead. You can find useful information about these two functions at https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy - check where your code is going to run in order to help you choose the best option.

In your code block you have this declaration

```
char *strings[10],string[50],*p;
```

This declares three pointers, but they are quite different. `*p` is an ordinary pointer, and must have space allocated for it (via `malloc`) before you can use it. `string[50]` is also a pointer, but of length 50 (characters, *usually* 1 byte) - and it's allocated on the function stack directly so you can use it right away (though the very first use of it should be to zero out the memory unless you've used a zeroing allocator like Solaris' `calloc`. Finally, `*strings[10]` is a *double* pointer - you have allocated an array of 10 pointers, each element of which (`strings[1]`, `strings[9]` etc) must be allocated for before use.

The only one of those which you can assign to immediately is `string`, because the space is already allocated. Each of those pointers can be addressed via subscripts - but in each case you must ensure that you do not walk off the end otherwise you'll incur a SIGSEGV "segmentation violation" and your program will crash. Or at least, it should, but you might instead get merely weird results.

Finally, pointers allocated to must be freed manually otherwise you'll have memory leaks. Items allocated on the stack (`string`) do not need to be freed because the compiler handles that for you when the function ends.